Windows with external hard drive in enclosure
I have a Kesu 2530 and Orico 25PW1 USB3.0 enclosure case. I use Seagate ST500LM030 and WDC WD10JPVX-08JC3T5, APPLE HDD HTS541010A99E662 2.5" hard drives.
In Windows 10 there is an eject function to safely remove hardware. When this function is executed, and the HDD + case does not appear in Windows, for example "E:" even with the USB3.0 cable connected to the PC on/case.
After all this happened, my hand hit the USB3.0 enclosure case and it moved on the table.
Did this hit cause friction between the 2.5" HDD read/write heads and the magnetic platters, scratching them?
image
